# loopback 4 : patch request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4, angular-loopback

I get an error when I send a patch request to my api (with loopback 4) , all the other request are working fine , i get error only on patch request .

error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url api' from origin 'url web app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

any idea please !! this problem it was also on loopback 3 , so i think if migrate to loopback 4 i will solve the problem , but i get always the same error

Comment: Try manually configuring CORS rules as described here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html#customize-cors

Comment: thanks for your help spirit  , i already did , here is code in index.ts :   const config = {
    rest: {
      port: +(process.env.PORT ?? 3000),
      host: process.env.HOST,
      gracePeriodForClose: 5000, // 5 seconds
      openApiSpec: {
        setServersFromRequest: true,
      },
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
        preflightContinue: false,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        maxAge: 86400,
        credentials: true,
      },
    },
  };

Comment: All rest methods work fine except patch method

Comment: See the response headers: Access-Control-* in the debugger, how they look for PATCH and for other requests?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://urlapi/preventives/56' from origin 'https://web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: {
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "Unknown Error",
    "url": "https://urlapi.com/preventives/56",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://urlapi.com/preventives/56: 0 Unknown Error",
    "error": {
        "isTrusted": true
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The same error came to me when i was using cors extension
After removing the extension it works for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you - worked for me. I just had to turn the extension off and PATCH requests started working